# Image segmentation with noisy labels

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, semi-supervised-learning

I have a dataset which consists of satellite images and their labels which are indicated by let say class 1 and 2. I want to perform image segmentation to detect pixels related to class 1 and 2. The main issue is that the labels for my dataset are obtained using another apporach and they contain some noise. For instance, some pixels should have been labeled as class 1, but in fact they are labeled as background. I wanted to ask if there is any approach for tarining using noisy labels?
As an idea I wanted to use a teacher and student approach: 1) start with a subset of clean labels 2) train a model using the clean labels. 3) generate sudo labels and filter out high queality labels 4) combine them with previously clean data 4) repeat the training process until a good performance is obtained.
However the main problem with this approach is that it is difficult to collect a subset of clean labels to start from. In addition, I have lots of labeled data which may be usefull during training although they are noisy.
I would appreciate it if you can suggest any usefull approach and resource as guidance to solve this issue?